# How to can I change the environment around a table to a table enviroment?

Tags: tables

I made a table with `tabular` which works fine. However, in order to apply the commands such as `\sffamily`, `\centering` etc. I put it into a `figure` as another table environment did not work (I possibly did something wrong).

However, the problem is that in the PDF it states "figure" though I want it to say "table". How can I solve this problem?

```latex
\begin{figure}[H]
\vspace{-0.6cm}
\centering
\sffamily 
\footnotesize
%\captionsetup{labelformat=empty} 
\caption{CAPTION}
\label{my-label} 
\begin{tabular}{lp{6.0cm}p{3.0cm}p{3.0cm}}
\hline
\textbf{X}   &\textbf{Y}        &\textbf{Z}\\\hline
A   & 1     & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: change `figure` to `table`

Comment: I just noticed it :D thanks